# Display accepted answers first

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer, sorting

It's kind of small but I'd like the ability to view a user's (mine or others') accepted answers before all of the other ones in their answers list.

Answer (score 6):

This shouldn't be too hard to implement (just a new sort order on the answer list). I don't know how much traction it would gain though. For me the black background on the vote total works well enough to separate them and I don't necessarily feel the need to sort them.

Comment: Besides, accepted answers tend to clump at the top.

Answer (score 3):

I like this idea, but I can't think of any time I'd be likely to use it.  I suppose it'd be handy to check how many people have accepted my answer without upvoting or something.  Maybe I'm just excited at the prospect of more options and things to click on.  I'm a lot like a toddler.

Comment: Added +1 for humor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would result in site-wide...OOOOH SHINY! Another ....option.... must.... click............. JOY!